# Grid Page for custom collection in Front end

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, search

We have a marketplace website, where we have list of vendors.

In a page, we need to **list all vendors** for customers, So that customers can search and filter by Vendor's `group, name, location`. It would reflect nearly the **Grid pages** in admin.

We have custom collection for it. But to display as searchable by every column for the customer has to be made.

I tried like grid making in Backend,here is the Block I'm using

```
<?php
class Probytes_Customization_Block_Listvendors extends VES_Vendors_Block_Adminhtml_Vendors_Grid {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_blockGroup = 'customization_listvendors';
        $this->_controller = 'customization_listvendors_index';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('customization')->__('Orders - Inchoo');

        parent::__construct();
    }
    protected function _prepareCollection() {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('vendors/vendor')->getCollection()
                        //->addNameToSelect()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('telephone')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('postcode')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('country_id')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('lastname')
                        ;
      //$collection->getSelect()->columns('CONCAT(firstname,lansname) as name');
      $this->setCollection($collection);
      return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
    protected function _prepareColumns()
  {

      $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
          'header'    => Mage::helper('vendors')->__('ID'),
          'align'     =>'right',
          'width'     => '50px',
          'index'     => 'entity_id',
      ));

      $this->addColumn('vendor_id', array(
          'header'    => Mage::helper('vendors')->__('Vendor'),
          'align'     =>'left',
          'width'     => '150px',
          'index'     => 'vendor_id',
      ));

      $this->addColumn('firstname', array(
          'header'    => Mage::helper('vendors')->__('First Name'),
          'align'     =>'left',
          'width'     => '150px',
          'index'     => 'firstname',
      ));

      $this->addColumn('lastname', array(
          'header'    => Mage::helper('vendors')->__('Last Name'),
          'align'     =>'left',
          'width'     => '150px',
          'index'     => 'lastname',
      ));

      $this->addColumn('group_id', array(
          'header'    => Mage::helper('vendors')->__('Group'),
          'align'     =>'left',
          'width'     => '150px',
          'type'      => 'options',
          'options'   => Mage::getModel('vendors/source_group')->getOptionArray(),
          'index'     => 'group_id',
      ));
      return parent::_prepareColumns();
  }
}
```

Then in the controller

```
public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customization/listvendors')->toHtml()
        );
        //$this->renderLayout();
    }
```

How to implement it in front end?

Comment: do you have any code so far? At least the block that should retrieve the vendors? If so, please post the code in the question.

Comment: @Marius  I have updated my block and controller code here